# How can I fix the MPI code for the requirements?

Tags: c, mpi

I have a written code for an assignment and it needs to be fixed as per the requirements. Can you please help me, my whole brain is already broken.

**Assignment:**
Compose a program using blocking and non-blocking operations according to the variant: b = MIN(A+C)
Provide execution of operations in several processes. Distribution of source
data should be performed using non-blocking operations, and the collection of results - using blocking ones.
results - using blocking operations.

**Requirements:**

1. The search for the minimum value must be performed in parallel.
2. Use only two-point operations.
3. Auxiliary processes in the subarray retrieval phase must know the size of the data being retrieved.
4. Checking if(rank==0) should be once in the code (this has already been fixed, but I'll leave it anyway).
5. Should not count everything on 0 process (this is very important).

**Notation:**

- a - scalar quantity
- A - vector of dimension N
- MA - matrix of dimension NxN
- a*B - product of vector by scalar
- a*MB - product of a matrix by a scalar
- (A*B) - scalar product of vectors A and B
- (MA*MB) - product of matrices MA and MB
- (MA*B) - product of matrix by vector
- SORT(A) - sorting vector A in ascending order
- MIN(A) - search for the minimum element of the vector
- MAX(A) - search for maximum element of the vector
- TRANS(MA) - transpose matrix MA
- MAX(MA) - search for maximal element of the matrix
- MIN(MA) - search for the minimum element of the matrix
- SORT(MA) - sorting matrix rows by descending order

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
const int N = 30;
int rank, size;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

int local_size = N / size;

srand(time(0) + rank);
int* A = new int[local_size];
int* C = new int[local_size];
for (int i = 0; i < local_size; i++)
{
    A[i] = rand() % 100;
    C[i] = rand() % 100;
}

printf("Process Rank: %d\n", rank);
printf("Vector A:");
for (int i = 0; i < local_size; i++)
{
    printf(" %d", A[i]);
}
printf("\n");

printf("Vector C:");
for (int i = 0; i < local_size; i++)
{
    printf(" %d", C[i]);
}
printf("\n");

int local_min_A = A[0];
int local_min_C = C[0]; 
for (int i = 0; i < local_size; i++)
{
    if (A[i] < local_min_A)
    {
        local_min_A = A[i];
    }
    if (C[i] < local_min_C)
    {
        local_min_C = C[i];
    }
}

int local_min_sum = local_min_A + local_min_C;

printf("Local b min(A + C) = %d + %d = %d\n", local_min_A, local_min_C, local_min_sum);

if (rank == 0)
{
    int global_min_A = local_min_A;
    int global_min_C = local_min_C;
    int global_min_sum = local_min_sum;

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        int recv_min_A, recv_min_C, recv_min_sum, recv_local_size;
        MPI_Recv(&recv_min_A, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_Recv(&recv_min_C, 1, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_Recv(&recv_min_sum, 1, MPI_INT, i, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        if (recv_min_A < global_min_A)
        {
            global_min_A = recv_min_A;
        }
        if (recv_min_C < global_min_C)
        {
            global_min_C = recv_min_C;
        }
        if (recv_min_sum < global_min_sum)
        {
            global_min_sum = recv_min_sum;
        }
    }

    printf("Global b min(A + C) = %d\n", global_min_sum);
}
else
{
    MPI_Send(&local_min_A, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&local_min_C, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&local_min_sum, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

delete[] A;
delete[] C;

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Example of sum calculation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;
#define n 40000000L
int main(int argc, char** argv){
int rank,size;
MPI_Status st;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
if (!rank){
double *x, sum=0, d;
x=new double[n];
srand((unsigned)time(0));
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
x[i]=(rand()%20)/2.;
unsigned pSize = n/(size-1);
printf("Master started!\n");
for (int i=1; i<size; i++) {
MPI_Send(&pSize,1,MPI_UNSIGNED,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(x+(i-1)*pSize,pSize,MPI_DOUBLE,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
cout << "Master sent " << 
pSize << endl;
}
for (int i=pSize*(size-1); i<n; i++)
sum+=x[i];
for (int i=1; i<size; i++) {
MPI_Recv(&d, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, i,MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);
cout << "Got sum from " << i<< ": sum="<< d << endl;
sum+=d;
}
cout << "Sum=" << sum << endl;
MPI_Finalize();
delete[] x;
return 0;
} else {
double *data, s = 0;
unsigned count;
data=new double[count];
MPI_Recv(&count, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0,MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);
MPI_Recv(data, count, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);
cout << "Rank " << rank << " got " << count << endl;
for (unsigned i=0; i<count; i++)
s+=data[i];
MPI_Send(&s,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Finalize();
delete[] data;
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: please help me fix my code

Comment: Please describe in more details what is wrong with your current solution.

Comment: I sent all the code requirements, I also added an example of calculating the amount, I must have done it wrong.

Comment: and what do you need to explain?

Comment: Explain what is not working and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @w4de to say it very roughly, YOU have a problem you need a solution for. YOU need to describe the problem well enough, that people can understand it an answer it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to improve the current question. Especially the part about a Minimally Reproducible Example

Answer (score 0):

> … b = MIN(A+C) …
>
> ```
> int local_min_A = A[0];
> int local_min_C = C[0]; 
> for (int i = 0; i < local_size; i++)
> {
>    if (A[i] < local_min_A)
>    {
>        local_min_A = A[i];
>    }
>    if (C[i] < local_min_C)
>    {
>        local_min_C = C[i];
>    }
> }
>
> int local_min_sum = local_min_A + local_min_C;
> ```

Instead of *MIN(A+C)* you compute MIN(A)+MIN(C).

Comment: I added the corrected code, but the operations there are not used in the same way